# Release error in Azure DevOps Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, rake

I am new to Azure DEvOps and want to implement a simple ruby on rails website. Tutorials that I see online are mostly focused in .Net. Following is my created azure-pipeline.yml file. The code builds without error but when I create a release with a Ruby on Rails template it gives error. [My error,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/993Hq.png)
[rakefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A88CT.png)
[and my build pipeline output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4baIn.png). Can anyone help me on this or refer to some azure devops tutorials for ruby on rails.

````
```
# Ruby
# Package your Ruby project.
# Add steps that install rails, analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/ruby

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UseRubyVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>= 3.0'
    addToPath: true

- script: |
    CALL gem install bundler
    bundle init
    gem install rake
    bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
  displayName: 'bundle install'

- script: bundle exec rake
  displayName: 'bundle exec rake'


- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
 
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifactType: 'pipeline'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```
````

Answer (score 0):

CI output is telling you where is the problem. Look for lines 24 and 53. `No rakefile found`.

[Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/command_line.html#rake) to know abut Rake. It is used for doing tasks, for example when you run `rails db:migrate`, rake is doing its job.

So you should add a Rakefile to the root of your application, with:

myapp/**Rakefile**

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require_relative "config/application"

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

EDIT:

try to change your yml to:

```
- script: |
    echo "gem: --no-document" > ~/.gemrc
    gem install bundler
    bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
  displayName: 'bundle install'

- script: bundle exec rake
  displayName: 'bundle exec rake'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have my rakefile in the directory with the required contents which I have added in my original question. Do you think I may need to add anything in my .yml file?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Idk if this could help

Comment: I tried it but the error is still the same. The error still says No rakefile found and could not locate gemfile not located.

Comment: Do you have any error if you remove `- script: bundle exec rake
  displayName: 'bundle exec rake'`?